# Vite React js AxiosError Doens't Handle in Catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, vite

I am sending a query to express js with axios. Express js sends an error code and even if it sends an error, axios does not run the catch block. I was not having such a problem when I was using Create React App. When I print the incoming data to the console, I see axios error but the catch block does not work.
example
Login response: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

How can I fix it?

Frontend Context

```
 const login = async (inputs) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", inputs);
    console.log("Login response:", res);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setCurrentUser(res.data);
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res.data));
    }
    return res; // Return the response
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Login error:", error);
    console.error("Login error:", error);
    return error.response; // Return the error response
  }
};
```

express js Backend

```
export const login = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER

  const schoolNo = parseInt(req.body.schoolNo, 10);
  const studentNo = parseInt(req.body.studentNo, 10);
  

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.Okul_Kodu = ? AND u.Ogrenci_No = ?";

  db.query(q, [schoolNo, studentNo], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length === 0)
      return res.status(500).json(err);
     (data[0]);

    // Check password
    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(
      req.body.password,
      data[0].Password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong username or password!");

    // Extract only the desired fields from the data
    const {
      Okul_Kodu,
      Ogrenci_No,
      Ogrenci_Adi,
      User_Role,
      Okul_Turu,
      id,
      sinif,
    } = data[0];

    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(data);
    // const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(data);
    // refreshTokens.push(refreshToken);
    //  ("login"+refreshToken);

    // Create a response object with the desired fields
    const responseObject = {
      id,
      Okul_Kodu,
      Ogrenci_No,
      Ogrenci_Adi,
      User_Role,
      Okul_Turu,
      accessToken,
      sinif,
    };

    res
      .cookie("access_token", accessToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(responseObject);
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you added any customisation to the Axios defaults? Specifically to `validateStatus`? Also, what version of Axios are you using?

Comment: I updated to the latest version of Axios (1.6.1) and I want to catch errors not only for validation but also for data fetching and data sending.